# php form to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, modal-dialog

I need to pass the form id to javascript, but always shows the same data.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function(){
        var vauid = $( "input[name='uid']"     ).val(); alert("\n ID:  "+vauid);
    return false;
    }); 
});
</script>                                               
<? include "../includes/config.php";
$sql = "select * from table";
$reg = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($reg)){ ?>
<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text"   name="uid"     value="<?  echo $row['uid']?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show"/>
</form> 
<? }?>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: not too sure but you can try this `var vauid  =  $( "input[name=uid]").val();` ..  i removed the single quotes around `uid`

Comment: That shouldn't matter @adelowo

Comment: @JayBlanchard oops,did not know that

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you're inserting numerous forms with elements having the same names - that is a bad idea as names are intended to be unique.

Second, when you click you have to reference the currently clicked info:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var vauid = $(this).prev("input[name='uid']").val(); 
        console.log("ID:  "+vauid);
    }); 
});
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4vk0adv/).

`$(this)` will be the clicked button from which we look for the previous input's value. I'm also using `preventDefault()` to stop the button's default action, rather than returning false.

In addition you should [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: names are not unique in a radio group. also an input in one form can have the same name as an input in another form.

Comment: You're absolutely right @dewd - I didn't say it was illegal, just a bad idea for single input elements. Radio groups have to be named the same in order to make them a group.

Comment: Thanks Jay.
But this method does not work, because I have to load a list of users of a database.

Comment: That is information that we weren't working with before @BMF - why doesn't this work? Loading the forms as you are doing should work just fine.

Comment: Jay, In the demo you have 2 form, but I need to load the list of users in the same form with a while pass the information of the selected user

Comment: If you can update what your form would *actually* look like I can modify my answer to help you out. I based my demo off of your original form and question @BMF

Comment: Jay again thanks your code works fine, my mistake is type first the script and then the form